# Bash exits after executing one command instead executing the rest of the script

Tags: shell, adb

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Would you like to delete Google Drive? (yes/no) " DRIVE
if [ "$DRIVE" == "yes" ]
then
    echo "Google Drive will be deleted."
    exec adb uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.apps.docs
elif [ "$DRIVE" == "no" ]
then
    echo "Google Drive will not be deleted."
else
    echo "It's a yes or no question!" 
fi

read -p "Would you like to delete Google Duo? (yes/no) " DUO#
if [ "$DUO" == "yes" ]
then
    echo "Google Duo will be deleted."
    exec adb uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.apps.tachyon
elif [ "$DUO" == "no" ]
then
    echo "Google Duo will not be deleted."
else
    echo "It's a yes or no question" 
fi
```

My problem is that it exits after exec adb uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.apps.docs

Answer (score 3):

```
exec adb uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.apps.docs
```

`exec` replaces the script with `adb` -- it'll never return from `exec`. Get rid of it, you don't need it.

```
adb uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.apps.docs
```

Comment: IMO, needs more emphasis: `exec` **replaces** the script process.

Comment: @computernoob14, then update your question with your actual code and show us what happens.

Comment: heres what happens when i run it in terminal [mickey@mickey-pc Documents]$ ./androidsetup.sh Would you like to delete Google Drive? (yes/no) yes
Google Drive will be deleted.
success

Comment: Did you actually change `exec adb` to just `adb`?